# Lottie animations in Android LG 3 not working

Tags: android, lottie

I have an animation that runs on my  Android app, it shows up on the emulator API 22, but doesn't show up on my phone (LG3 API 21)

Java:

```
    LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView = (LottieAnimationView) findViewById(R.id.animation_view);
    lottieAnimationView.setImageAssetsFolder("images/");
    lottieAnimationView.setAnimation("GM_part_1.json");
    lottieAnimationView.loop(false);
    lottieAnimationView.useExperimentalHardwareAcceleration(true);
    lottieAnimationView.enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove(true);
    lottieAnimationView.playAnimation();
```

layout:

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    app:lottie_imageAssetsFolder="images"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/animation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Any ideas why this happens? And how I can fix it?